# Expensive IEnumerable: Any way to prevent multiple enumerations without forcing an immediate enumeration?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a very large enumeration and am preparing an expensive **deferred** operation on it (e.g. sorting it). I'm then passing this into a function which may or may not consume the IEnumerable, depending on some logic of its own.

Here's an illustration:

```cs
IEnumerable<Order> expensiveEnumerable = fullCatalog.OrderBy(c => Prioritize(c));
MaybeFullFillSomeOrders(expensiveEnumerable);

// Elsewhere... (example use-case for multiple enumerations, not real code)
void MaybeFullFillSomeOrders(IEnumerable<Order> nextUpOrders){
    if(notAGoodTime())
       return;
    foreach(var order in nextUpOrders)
       collectSomeInfo(order);
    processInfo();
    foreach(var order in nextUpOrders) {
       maybeFulfill(order);
       if(atCapacity())
          break;
    }
}
```

I'm would like to prepare my input to the other function such that:

1. If they do not consume the enumerable, the performance price of sorting is not paid.

   - This already precludes calling e.g. `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on it
2. If they choose to enumerate multiple times (perhaps not realizing how expensive it would be in this case) I want some defence in place to prevent the multiple enumeration.
3. Ideally, the result is still an `IEnumerable<T>`

The best solution I've come up with is to use `Lazy<>`

```cs
var expensive = new Lazy<List<Order>>>(
    () => fullCatalog.OrderBy(c => Prioritize(c)).ToList());
```

This appears to satisfy criteria 1 and 2, but has a couple of drawbacks:

- I have to change the interface to all downstream usages to expect a `Lazy`.
- The full list (which in this case was built up from a `SelectMany()` on serveral smaller partitions) would need to be allocated as a new single contiguous list in memory. I'm not sure there's an easy way around this if I want to "cache" the sort result, but if you know of one I'm all ears.

One idea I had to solve the first problem was to wrap `Lazy<>` in some custom class that either implements or can implicitly be converted to an `IEnumerable<T>`, but I'm hoping someone knows of a more elegant approach.

Comment: MoreLinq has an extension called `Memoize` in its "Experimental" namespace that does this. It is however "experimental". https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Experimental/Memoize.cs

Comment: The author of that method should already be getting a warning about possible multiple enumeration. They're also most easily able to identify the right point at which to enumerate the items and store them - i.e. the usual way to fix this is for that receiving method to be changed. Why are you thinking differently here in such a way that you encourage non-portable thinking about `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's a good question. The best answer I can come up with is purely situational - this is a legacy codebase and I am fixing a bug (things not processed in the right order) which changes what used to be a cheap-to-enumerate enumerable, into an expensive one. I don't trust myself to catch all downstream multiple enumerations, and would prefer not to have to refactor all that code. I'm hoping I can contain the fix here without slowing down the application horribly as a direct result.

Comment: @Alain The better solution in that case would probably be to change the enumerator so it *can't* be enumerated multiple times, so that you can then find all of the problematic places and fix them, rather than trying to cover up the problem.  If materializing the collection into a list is unacceptably expensive (which is a part of your premise, if it weren't doing that would be the solution) then memorization won't be much better, since it will need to store all of the items in the sequence eventually.  If it's too expensive to do at the start, it's probably too expensive to do later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You certainly *could* write your own `IEnumerable<T>` implementation that wraps another one, remembering all the elements it's already seen (and whether it's exhausted or not). If you need it to be thread-safe that becomes trickier, and you'd need to remember that at any time there may be multiple iterators working against the same `IEnumerable<T>`.

Fundamentally I think it would come down to working out what to do when asked for the next element (which is somewhat-annoyingly split into `MoveNext()` and `Current`, but that can probably be handled...):

- If you've already read the next element within another iterator, you can yield it from your buffer
- If you've already discovered that there *is* no next element, you can return that immediately
- Otherwise, you need to ask the original iterator for the next element, and remember if for all the other wrapped iterators.

The other aspect that's tricky is knowing when to dispose of the underlying `IEnumerator<T>` - if you don't need to do that, it makes things simpler.

As a *very* sketchy attempt that I haven't even attempted to compile, and which is *definitely* not thread-safe, you could try something like this:

```cs
public class LazyEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> iterator;
    private List<T> buffer;
    private bool completed = false;

    public LazyEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> original)
    {
        // TODO: You could be even lazier, only calling
        // GetEnumerator when you first need an element
        iterator = original.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            // If we already have the element, yield it
            if (index < buffer.Count)
            {
                yield return buffer[index];
            }
            // If we've yielded everything in the buffer and some
            // other iterator has come to the end of the original,
            // we're done.
            else if (completed)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            // Otherwise, see if there's anything left in the original
            // iterator.
            else
            {
                bool hasNext = iterator.MoveNext();
                if (hasNext)
                {
                    var current = iterator.Current;
                    buffer.Add(current);
                    yield return current;
                }
                else
                {
                    completed = true;
                    yield break;
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```